# Capybara poltergeist not executing the mdc webpack application.js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist, mdc-components

I have a rails 5 running application. I am using mdc components for styling. 
I have a javascript function that calls new mdc.mdcTextFeild(.....)

This works perfectly fine in a browser environment. But while testing using capybara with poltergeist driver, I am able to see my application-XXXXXX.js present inside the HTML but however, it throws Reference error mdc not found!

I am using web-pack to load mdc components.It's compiling properly and loads the script. However, the window object inside the poltergeist doesn't have mdc defined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poltergeist uses PhantomJS as its "browser". The latest release version of PhantomJS is basically equivalent to a 6-7 year old browser and doesn't support a lot of modern JS/CSS. Because of this any modern JS needs to be transpiled and polyfilled to be ES5 compatible (no `let`, `const`, `Array.from`, `Array.of`, etc), or you will have JS errors which prevent a lot of the page behavior loading.

You're probably going to be much better off using Capybara with Selenium and headless chrome, instead of Poltergeist, for any headless testing of modern apps nowadays.